# Concat 2 video and add watermark first video ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, linux

I have a Video #1, it has audio. Also I have a Video #2, with audio too. I would like to concat the #1 and #2 (or play #1 first, and then #2) and then add a watermark in #1 for the rest of the video, preserving audio timestamps.

I used this command but the watermark appears on the #2 video?

```
ffmpeg -i Video1.mp4 -i Video2.mp4 -i watermark.png
   -filter_complex
       "[1][2]overlay=5:5[v2];
        [0][0:a][v2][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1"
   -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -movflags  faststart Out.mp4
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate can be found from [this link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

In case of using same codec

```
!echo "file 'video_1.mp4'" > list.txt
!echo "file 'video_2.mp4'" >> list.txt
```

Add watermark at (x=1, y=1) coordinated

```
!ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=1:1" output.mp4
```

I don't quite understand your description, but i think it fits your title.